# how can i run an interactive shell in docker from python code

Tags: docker, shell, subprocess, popen, interactive

my code should send several commands and their expected results to be executed on a docker container one after another in case each result was as expected.
The problem is that i dont get any output.
what am i doing wrong?

at first i tried to send a single command, 'ls -ltra' , and get its result, but i didnt get any output:

```
import time
import os
import subprocess
c = 'docker exec -it node1 /bin/bash'
p = subprocess.Popen(c, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
os.set_blocking(p.stdout.fileno(), False)
start = time.time()
command = 'ls -ltra'
p.stdin.write(command)
p.stdin.flush()
while p.poll() is None and time.time() - start < 10:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    print(output)
    print(p.stdout.flush())
    time.sleep(0.5)
p.communicate(input=b"\x04".decode()) #close the shell
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.close()
p.terminate()
```

i cant do it with communicate because the command can be a one that will need continuous interaction.like for example, password or exit().
i appreciate any thoughts for what will be the possible reason & potential fix in the python code.
Thanx

Comment: `should send several commands` why not just `docker exec node1 /bin/bash -c "command1 && command2"`? Why interactive, if you want non-interactive? `-t` you requested a _terminal_. Do you want to handle terminal size changes and colors and other ANSI escape sequences?

Comment: because i send a list of (command,expected_result) if i get the expected result i send the next command. for example, command='ls' check if  'tmp' is in output , send echo 'bla' > /tmp/file.txt

Comment: `if [[ -e tmp ]]; then echo 'bla' > /tmp/file.txt; fi`. Bash is a full programming language. Python is also a full programming language. There is nothing interactive in your code. You could also do in python `if "tmp" in subprocess.check_output("docker run node1 ls"): subprocess.check("docker run node1 tee /tmp/file.txt", input="bla")`. Related [do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). You can also pickle python objects and execute python inside the container. Overall, all it is not interactive.

Comment: my container is running. i just gave an example for a simple command that doesnt work. i want to be able to send  a request to the docker containing list of commands(inputs) which wont block. the inputs are to be executed in the same shell  on the container, according to the output . if its inserting username or password or quit() or any other input needed . thats why i need it to be interactive. i need the shell to stay open as long as i interact on it. the interaction can be also time consuming like waiting for a specific output in a many lines output